# Issue with 512 app icon showing gloss

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I created an app for iphone and in my project plist settings I set UIPrerenderedIcon to true. Meaning apple shouldn't put that nasty gloss over my icons. Now when I uploaded my app for review and created a large 512x512 pixel icon it put the gloss over it. Check this link for my app.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/quick-movie-camera/id490749849?ls=1&mt=8

Now if you download my app, which I encourage *smile*, you will see that the icons that get displayed on the iphone have NO gloss on them yet this big preview picture of my app shows gloss. What gives?

Now here's the confounding thing, I created another app and its large 512x has no gloss

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/quick-pics-camera/id490511603?ls=1&mt=8

The setting of plist file for both the projects are identical as far as I can tell.

Comment: From what I gather this is a known BUG that apple is aware of since Aug 2011 yet they didn't fix it? That cant be right? http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/88322-app-logo-still-glossy-512-px-2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has fixed this bug in their itunes store. (fix was sometime in Jan/Feb 2012)